# How to access all 16 dimensions like lord shiva?

Tags: shiva

I have been surfing the Internet , and found that lord shiva has access to all the 16 dimensions. Can anyone give someone please verify whether such claims are true. If true how can any person transcend  the 3 dimensions to get access to such 16 dimensions. Thank you.